How to add a custom claim to Azure AD dispensed JWT access token
myApplication authenticates and fetch a JWT access token from Azure AD. BackendSystem is authorizing myApplication based on the claims in JWT access token.
Decoded JWT
{
  "aud": "abc",
  "iss": "https://sts.windows.net/6xxxf/",
  "iat": 1721983095,
  "nbf": 1721983095,
  "exp": 1721986995,
  "aio": "Exx=",
  "appid": "ID",
  "appidacr": "x",
  "idp": "https://sts.windows.net/6xxxf/",
  "oid": "1xxx2",
  "rh": "0xxx.",
  "roles": [
    "roles"
  ],
  "sub": "1xxx2",
  "tid": "TID",
  "uti": "YxxA",
  "ver": "xxx"
}

In this list of claims, I would like to add a new custom claim Example which is not part of the additional standard claims that are offered by Azure AD.
New JWT:
{
  "aud": "abc",
  "iss": "https://sts.windows.net/6xxxf/",
  "iat": 1721983095,
  "nbf": 1721983095,
  "exp": 1721986995,
  "aio": "Exx=",
  "appid": "ID",
  "appidacr": "x",
  "idp": "https://sts.windows.net/6xxxf/",
  "oid": "1xxx2",
  "rh": "0xxx.",
  "roles": [
    "roles"
  ],
  "sub": "1xxx2",
  "tid": "TID",
  "uti": "YxxA",
  "ver": "xxx",
  "Example": "abc-123"
}

I'm new to Azure AD and found option to add only the optional standard claims (given_name, family_name, etc.) offered by Azure AD. How can I implement this?
Please note: This is not for SSO. myApplication will not be sending this additional custom claim in the request to Azure AD.

Check this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/1606464/using-client-credential-flow-how-can-i-add-a-custo

Based on the decoded token you provided, you are using client credential flow to generate access token.

Note that: Adding custom attribute or claims is not supported in client credential flow. Refer this Microsoft QnA by Shweta Mathur.


Only claims that can be used in the custom mapping policy for client credential flow is displayname, objectid and tags.
Hence it is not feasible to customize the claim using client credential flow.

Hence you can add only the above-mentioned claims in the token by creating claim mapping policy like below:
Create a policy:
New-AzureADPolicy -Definition @('{"ClaimsMappingPolicy": {"Version": 1,"ClaimsSchema":[
{"Source": "application","ID": "DisplayName","JwtClaimType": "AppName"}]}}') -DisplayName "Claim-displayname" -Type "ClaimsMappingPolicy"

Assign the policy to Service Principal:
Add-AzureADServicePrincipalPolicy -Id SPObjID -RefObjectId PolicyID


Now I generated token via client credential flow:
https://login.microsoftonline.com/TenantID/oauth2/v2.0/token

client_id:ClientID
client_secret:ClientSecret
scope↵:api://xxx/.default
grant_type:client_credentials


When decoded the token, custom claim is displayed:


But you cannot create claim based on your requirement and get it in the token.

Reference:
azure - Entra External ID custom claim in client id token not in ASP.NET Core Web API User's ClaimsPrincipal - Stack Overflow by me
