Does Azure's EntraID support dynamic custom claims?
I need to dynamically add a custom claim to a token requested from EntraId for intra-application authentification.
I have an azure api management (apim) instance that authenticates a client request via the given subscription key. The subscription key is linked to a product and i need to pass on this product information to my backend api, which is a data-api-builder (dab) instance. Dab accepts jwt authentication and accepts custom roles if they are present in the jwt and the X-MS-API-ROLE header.
Hence my idea was to have apim request a token (client_credentials flow) from EntraId with the custom role claim dynamically set in the request and pass on the token.
<set-body>@{
    return "client_id={client_id}" + 
           "&client_secret={client_secret}" + 
           "&scope=api://{app_id}/.default" + 
           "&grant_type=client_credentials" + 
           "&claims=" + Uri.EscapeDataString("{\"roles\":\"" + context.Variables["productId"] + "\"}");
}</set-body>

Unfortunately, it seems that, while entraid does issue a token with the correct audience, my custom claims are simply omitted. My research seems to indicate that the client_credentials grant type does not support custom claims. Is this correct?
How could I work around this limitation of the identity provider?

Yes client credential flow do not support custom claims check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78847337/how-to-add-a-custom-claim-to-azure-ad-dispensed-jwt-access-token/78852000#78852000

And paste the screenshot of Api permissions blade of the application

@Rukmini I did not set any api permission. It only has the default graph read permission.

I see that you are passing &scope=api://{app_id}/.default which scope is that?

@Rukmini In my understanding .default is like a wildcard scope. "The .default scope is used to refer generically to a resource service (API) in a request, without identifying specific permissions." When i set up the application registration in EntraId i left everything on default, as my intention was that I'd only need to have the registration as a shell for the application id, so that the audience in the jwt could be set to a common value.

What is the aud value you want in the token?

Dab's jwt authentification needs to be configured with issuer and audience to check for. (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-api-builder/authentication-azure) So since i can set that value, my idea was to create a single application that simply provides me with an app_id/audience that i can set for both, the request in the apim policy and the validation in the dab configuration. Is that a valid approach?

Let us continue this discussion in chat.


Note that: If you are making use of Client Credential flow, then you cannot configure custom claims or dynamic custom claims.


Claims like displayname, objectid and tags can only be used in the custom mapping policy for client credential flow.

If you want to add the above claims, then check the below:
Create a  policy:
New-AzureADPolicy -Definition @('{"ClaimsMappingPolicy": {"Version": 1,"ClaimsSchema":[
{"Source": "application","ID": "DisplayName","JwtClaimType": "AppName"}]}}') -DisplayName "Claim-displayname" -Type "ClaimsMappingPolicy"

Assign the policy to Service Principal:
Add-AzureADServicePrincipalPolicy -Id SPObjID -RefObjectId PolicyID



Generated  token  via client credential flow:
https://login.microsoftonline.com/TenantID/oauth2/v2.0/token

client_id:ClientID
client_secret:ClientSecret
scope↵:api://xxx/.default
grant_type:client_credentials

When decoded the token, custom claim is displayed:


As you want the claims to be added dynamically by APIM on request to Entra ID, then you need to configure a custom identity provider.

Reference:
using client credential flow, how can I add a custom claim to the access token - Microsoft Q&A by Shweta Mathur.
