Azure Entra ID custom data in access token
probably stupid question but i will ask anyway - is there a way to add custom data to an access token when generating token through calling entra id token endpoint with client credentials flow?
Something like pseudo code when client calls https://login.microsoftonline.com/xxx/oauth2/v2.0/token
body = {
myCustomValue: "whatever"
}
and I'd receive a token which would magically contain a claim with value "whatever" ...
Thanks for any input

Could you confirm whether your requirement is to add custom data to access token generated with client credentials flow? If that's the case, it's not possible.

@sridevi - yes. i wanted to use client credentials flow to generate the token. just out of curiosity - how would i add custom data with authorization code flow request ?

Note that, adding custom claims to the token generated with client credentials flow is not supported. Refer this MS Q&A by Shweta Mathur.
Alternatively, switch to delegated flows like authorization code flow or interactive flows where user needs to login at least once.
Initially, create one claim mapping policy by running below sample Microsoft Graph PowerShell script and get it's policy ID:
#Install-Module Microsoft.Graph
Connect-MgGraph -Scopes "Policy.ReadWrite.ApplicationConfiguration,Policy.ReadWrite.ConditionalAccess,Policy.Read.All,Application.ReadWrite.All,User.ReadWrite.All"
$policyDefinition = @{
    definition = '{
        "ClaimsMappingPolicy": {
            "Version": 1,
            "IncludeBasicClaimSet": true,
            "ClaimsSchema": [
                {"Source": "user", "ID": "extensionattribute1", "SamlClaimType": "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/myCustomValue", "JwtClaimType": "myCustomValue"}
            ]
        }
    }'
    displayName = "CustomClaim"
}

$Policy = New-MgPolicyClaimMappingPolicy -BodyParameter $policyDefinition
Get-MgPolicyClaimMappingPolicy -ClaimsMappingPolicyId $Policy.Id | fl

Response:

Now, assign this policy to the service principal from which you are generating the token with these commands:
$servicePrincipalId = "spObjectId" 
$policyId = "policyId" 

$params = @{
    "@odata.id" = "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/policies/claimsMappingPolicies/$policyId"
}

New-MgServicePrincipalClaimMappingPolicyByRef -ServicePrincipalId $servicePrincipalId -BodyParameter $params
Get-MgServicePrincipalClaimMappingPolicy -ServicePrincipalId $servicePrincipalId | fl

Response:

Now, update  myCustomValue  claim value in user's properties by running these commands:
$userId = "userId"

$params = @{
    onPremisesExtensionAttributes = @{
        extensionAttribute1 = "myOwnValue"
    }
}
Update-MgUser -UserId $userId -BodyParameter $params


In your app registration, expose an API and add custom scope in it like this:

Make sure to enable below settings in app registration's Manifest:

Before generating the access token, don't miss adding and consenting custom API permission like this:

While generating access token using authorization code, make sure to use scope value as api://appId/access_as_user.
Authorization request:
https://login.microsoftonline.com/tenantId/oauth2/v2.0/authorize? 
client_id=appId
&response_type=code  
&redirect_uri=https://jwt.ms
&response_mode=query  
&scope=api://appId/access_as_user
&state=12345


Token request:
POST https://login.microsoftonline.com/tenantId/oauth2/v2.0/token

client_id:appId
client_secret:secret
grant_type:authorization_code
scope: api://appId/access_as_user
code:code
redirect_uri: https://jwt.ms


When I decoded above token in jwt.ms website, it has custom claim in it as below:

Reference:
Add organisation chart to Azure Active Directory token claims - Stack Overflow

Hi @Sridevi, I think this is not what I originally tried to get. In you example, you create a claim "MyCustomValue" with static value "MyOwnValue", but what i asked about is, if there's a way to specify the value of this claim during generating token request. Or did I miss something ?

Are you trying to set dynamic values for custom claims? If that's the case, it's not possible https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78973797/does-azures-entraid-support-dynamic-custom-claims
